# handling layout from a child-view Android

Tags: android, android-layout

to make it short.

I'm developing an Android note-taking program. Here is what I want to do:
I have a custom class extending view, and I add this custom view(named View01) to my main layout when my program launch(onCreate). Then I want to add another view(either to my main layout, or to other possible layout) when I double click on my current view(View01).
My code is like:(this is part in my onTouchEvent function of View01)

```
public class NotePanel extends View {

private long startTime;
private long endTime;
private DrawPanel drawPanel;
private LinearLayout drawLayout;
final private int pressingTime = 600;
private Context applicationContext;

public NotePanel(Context applicationContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(applicationContext);
    //this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    startTime=0;
    endTime=0;
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        System.out.println("click");
    }

    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(endTime-startTime);
        if (endTime-startTime >= pressingTime){

            drawPanel = new DrawPanel(this.applicationContext);
            //drawPanel.setVisibility(GONE);

            drawPanel.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            //drawLayout = new LinearLayout(applicationContext);
            drawLayout.addView(drawPanel);

        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that I can't even do anything to the drawLayout in View01, I'm new to Android Developing so I'm getting puzzled here. Is it only classes extending "Activity" can handle layouts?

Thanks a lot for all your attention.

Comment: "can't even do anything to the drawLayout in View01" -Can you explain more about this portion? What is this anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is something like:

Lest say I have two classes: `View01` that extends `view` and `View02` that also extends `view`. So to add a view to a layout I would do this:

```
public class NotePanel extends ViewGroup {

private long startTime;
private long endTime;
private DrawPanel drawPanel;
//private LinearLayout drawLayout;
final private int pressingTime = 600;

public NotePanel(Context applicationContext) {
    super(applicationContext);
    startTime=0;
    endTime=0;
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    drawPanel = new DrawPanel(applicationContext);
    this.addView(drawPanel);
    //drawLayout = new LinearLayout(applicationContext);
    //drawLayout.addView(drawPanel);
}
public NotePanel(Context applicationContext, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(applicationContext);
    startTime=0;
    endTime=0;
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    drawPanel = new DrawPanel(applicationContext);
    this.addView(drawPanel);
}

@Override 
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r,int b){

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        System.out.println("click");
    }

    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(endTime-startTime);
        if (endTime-startTime >= pressingTime){
            drawPanel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            drawPanel.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);              
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope that helps. Also I assume that you know how to add `view01`, if not tell me and I can put an example.

Comment: I tried this but when ACTION_DOWN is triggered, the app will be forced closed and I get this: exception dispatching input event; exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback... I have updated some of my code to the question, would you be so kind to take a look?

Comment: If you are extending View you need at least two constructors, look at the code I posted...also why are you not doing a switch statement?

Comment: Ok that is a good start...update your code with what you change so I can take a look.

Comment: sorry I just overwrote your code by mistake, it is what I get know.

Comment: Np. One thing, what is the root layout where you are putting your views?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14814/discussion-between-0gravity-and-master-yi)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting drawLayout as global variable and set it in onCreate, not onTouch. Should be able to reference it from onTouch with it being global.

You'll get many onTouch events with each touch too. You might have to check when finger is up, then add... so you don't add a bunch of them and get another problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to define your own event type and event listener interface in your custom view. When the appropriate user gestures are detected, the view can then notify any registered listener of the event. Then implement a custom event listener in your activity and it can respond to the event by updating the contents of the container layout.